# Extract video frames display time and frame number

Tags: video, ffmpeg, extract, vlan, frame

I would like to extract each frame and its display time. The purpose will be to later compare the output between two videos (reference/original video and the transmitted video) and see what frames are missing. I plan on using Big Buck Bunny (http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/) as my sample video.

FFMPEG seems to be the tool to use for this, but I haven't found the correct combination of options to use for my use case.

I am expecting my output to resemble something like:

```
    frame = 1, time = 0
    frame = 2, time = 2
    frame = 3, time = 3
    ...
    frame 14315, time = 596
```

I am hoping that the degraded video would show signs of degradation via its  output with frames missing and time out of sync.

Comment: When you say *extract*, do you mean to save the frame as an image?

Answer (score 4):

Try filter [showinfo](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showinfo). Seems like it's what you need. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.ts -vf "showinfo" -f null /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not *probing* the video? `ffprobe` is a great tool for this, bundled along with `ffmpeg`.

```
ffprobe -select_streams v:0 FILE_PATH -show_frames
```